# unable to understand the  output of first code while comparing 3 arguments in the if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

this is  a small code that compares the 3 variables at a go . I have compared 2 codes.

**FIRST**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
if( 8 > 7 > 6) std::cout << "true";
else std::cout << "false";
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << (8 < 9); 
std::cout << "\n";
system("pause");
}
// output :
/* false
 * 1
 */
```

**SECOND**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
if( 8 > (7 > 6) ) std::cout << "true"; // with brackets
else std::cout << "false";
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << (8 < 9); 
std::cout << "\n";
system("pause");
}
// output :
// true
// 1
```

*I understand the second output but can't understand how is the `if`statement in the first code is evaluated ?*
 Please explain.

Answer (score 7):

The relational operators are left-to-right, so `8>7>6` gets evaluated as (`8>7)>6`. `8>7` evaluates to `true`, which is converted to `1`, so you get `1>6`, which is `false`.

The C++ standard actually mentions this point explicitely:

> The relational operators group left-to-right. [Example: a<b<c means (a<b)<c and not (a<b)&&(b<c). ]

Answer (score 3):

`if( 8 > 7 > 6)` means `if( (8 > 7) > 6)` which means `if( (1) > 6)` which means `if(false)`. That means, `if` block cannot execute, `else` block will be executed which prints `false`.

`if( 8 > (7 > 6))` means `if( ( 8 > (1) )` which means `if(true)`. So `if` block gets executed which prints `true`.

And the value of `(8<9)` is easy to know if you know what `<` means.  Well, `(8<9)` returns `true` which means `1`.

Comment: @steve: Yes. Every language has full right to define how they define the behavior of the operators. There is no such thing as universal language.

Comment: @steve: of course it depends on the language, after all there is no all knowing programmer that dictates everything. Also you don't compare three values, what you are doing is not a bright idea even if you intend to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The first code's if statement is evaluated in left-to-right order. ie: `(8 > 7) > 6` which is evaluated as follows:

```
(8 > 7) > 6
(1) > 6
0
```

Note that `(8 > 7)` is `true`, so it returns the numerical equivalent for `true`, `1`.

The overall evaluation comes to `0`, ie. `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that immediately after I posted too. I quick-edited that.

Comment: Apparently quick enough for Stackoverflow to not add an "edited X mins ago" note... interesting. Didn't know it did that.

Answer (score 2):

An if statement is classically made to compare 2 statements,  if you are wanting to compare more than 2 statements you should be using a boolean OR `||` or a boolean AND `&&`.   The reasoning behind this is based in boolean logic.   The statement that you posted in the first program evaluates from left to right meaning

```
if (8 >7)>6
```

If 8 is greater than 7 (which it is) it will evaluate to true, which is "1" in boolean logic (1 being true, 0 being false).
Thus after that evaluates you have:

```
if (1 > 6)
```

which naturally evaluates to false.   Because the comparison is no longer 8/7/6,  it's true / 6. And in this case, true is less than 6, thus a false.

If you were to set it up like this, would would have the expected results:

```
if (8 > 7 && 7 > 6)//Do stuff
```

or alternatively, if you wanted to be exhaustive..

```
if (8 > 7 && 7 > 6 && 8 > 6)
```

so all numbers are compared (this would be more sensible in the event that you had 3 variables, perhaps where x should be equal to 100, y should be equal to 50, and z should be equal to 25.)

You'd then have the comparison

```
if (x > y && y > z && x > y) //do stuff
```

This would evaluate to true in the event that your variables had the contents that you expected.

Answer (score 0):

if(8 > 7 > 6) is evaluated like :

```
if((8 > 7) > 6)
if(true > 6)
true is implicitly casted to 1. 
1 > 6 is false.
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is evaluated left to right so it is the same as (8>7)>6.

8>7 is true which is equal to 1 so then it evaluates 1>6 which is false.

Answer (score 0):

The relational operators associate from left to right!
8>7>6 = (8>7)>6 = 1>6 = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

The associativity of operator ">" is from left to right, so it means that in your first example, "8 > 7" is evaluated first, and the result of that is 1, which is then evaluated against 6, which result is false.

In the second example, since you use brackets, the we have 8 > 1, which is true.

Hope this helps.